# Как сделать сетку постов как в pinterest

Tags: html, bootstrap

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы сетка была как в pinterest 
Вот код который я написал (используется bootstrap 5):

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-5 g-4  justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card my-2">
                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-company-1/500/image-1024.png"
                    class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чистым CSS это сделать нельзя. Pinterest просто при загрузке картинок вычисляет их смещение. ```style="top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translateX(825px) translateY(249px); width: 252px; height: 568px;"```